# Duplicate BuildConfig integrating Unity Ads in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, ide

I just finished my application and I'm trying to put ads in with Unity Ads.
I went to "File", "Import Module".
Next I went to "File", "Structure Projects", I clicked on my main module, and went to the dependencies tab on the right and clicked the + and 3.Module dependency, and I selected the module of my main
module depends. Now the code is fine.
But when I test my app, the grade build shows me that :
:unityads:compileReleaseJava
:unityads:proguardRelease
Note: there were 1 duplicate class definitions.(http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/
troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
:unityads:proguardRelease FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':unityads:proguardRelease'.

> java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/Appli/AndroidStudioProjects/The33/unityads/build/
>   intermediates/bundles/release/classes.jar] (Can't read [/Users/Appli/AndroidStudioProjects/The33/
>   unityads/libs/unity-ads.jar(;;;;;;!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)] (Duplicate zip entry [unity-ads.jar:com/
>   unity3d/ads/android/BuildConfig.class]))
>   The Gradle build script for my core project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
defaultConfig {
applicationId "studio.pomme.m.the33"
minSdkVersion 8
targetSdkVersion 21
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
release {
minifyEnabled false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile project(':unityads')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:6.5.87'
}
```

The Gradle build script for one of the library projects:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
    defaultConfig {}
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/unity-ads.jar')
}
```

I have no idea of what I should to do.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the problem is that the Unity Ads JAR contains BuildConfig class, which is also generated during the build process. The solution was to import the module using the AAR instead of the JAR.

1. Remove the existing Unity Ads module ("File"->"Project Structure").
2. Download the Unity Ads SDK.
3. Create a module from "unity-ads.aar" ("File"->"New"->"New Module"->"Import JAR/AAR package").